# Why am I getting the following error - Error in gsub("^(", x[1, ]) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, gsub

Some part of the data is -

```
[1] "(39.341209, -76.683117)" "(39.29686, -76.605532)"  "(39.293453, -76.689391)"
[4] "(39.370493, -76.609812)" "(39.279819, -76.623911)" "(39.286027, -76.627846)"
[7] "(39.295866, -76.576427)" "(39.364311, -76.617699)" "(39.343906, -76.635426)"
```

I splitted the data into two as follows -

```
      [,1]         [,2]          
[1,] "(39.341209" " -76.683117)"
[2,] "(39.29686"  " -76.605532)"
[3,] "(39.293453" " -76.689391)"
[4,] "(39.370493" " -76.609812)"
[5,] "(39.279819" " -76.623911)"
[6,] "(39.286027" " -76.627846)"
[7,] "(39.295866" " -76.576427)"
[8,] "(39.364311" " -76.617699)"
[9,] "(39.343906" " -76.635426)"
```

But now, I want to remove the parenthesis. I tried using gsub but it gave me an error -

Error in gsub("^(", x[ ,1]) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

What could be wrong in this?

I have made the changes and the parenthesis at the beginning got removed but now I want the other parenthesis also to be removed.

I tried using -

```
y<-gsub('$\\)','',y)
```

But no changes occurred. What should I do now?

Comment: `gsub` expects minimum 3 arguments, you are passing only 2. Read `?gsub`. Also "(" has a special meaning in regex so you need to escape it.

Comment: `x <- "(39.341209";
gsub("^.", "", x)`

Comment: Thanks got it! Checked it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all the round brackets you can use

```
y <- gsub('[()]', '', y)
```

To remove the opening round bracket from the start and closing bracket from the end use :

```
y <- gsub('^\\(|\\)$', '', y)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(y, whitespace = "[()]")
#[1] "39.341209, -76.683117"
```

#### data

```
y <- "(39.341209, -76.683117)"
```